# Can Nativescript 4.0 new Frame use more elements than Tabview or Sidedrawer?

Tags: nativescript

I see that Frame works now much better.
We can have Tabview,that is a root of current view.

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <TabViewItem title="First">
        <Frame defaultPage="home/home-page" />
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Second">
        <Frame defaultPage="second/second-page" />
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

This looks like home-page or second-page is “included”.

Now, i’m wondering if it’s possible to have app-root.xml that holds common elements, and needed page is included. I’ve tried this, but this is not working (why? This approach is possible only for tabview and sidedrawer ?)

app-root.xml

```
<Page>
    <Frame defaultPage="create/create"></Frame>
</Page>
```

create/create.xml

```
<StackLayout class="footer white">
            <Label text="test"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Page` use layout like `GridLayout` Look a[t this test application](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/e2e/modal-navigation) as a reference and more specifically [this page](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/e2e/modal-navigation/app/layout-root.android.xml)

However, the above approach would work for Android but for iOS, you should either remove the action bar for each `Page` (inside each `Frame`) or create multiple action bars (not recommended!).